# Reinforce awning pole made from 2x4?

Tags: wood, patio

I'm building a rudimentary awning with 2x4 treated lumber that I'm not using. One of the two "legs" of the awning looks like this. There's going to be a 2x4 attached to the concrete wall, and two 2x4's attached to it. The final result looks like below.

Considering that the top 2x4 is **6ft** long, my concern is that it will be too heavy for the 2x4 attached to the wall. I've seen many DIYs doing something like this, but the upper leg isn't that long.

What do you guys recommend?

[image]

Comment: You've asked about forty questions in the past year but have "selected" hardly any.  Completing  format will help the site and the users.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.

Comment: How far apart are the two "legs". Also, what region of the country do you live in? I need this for snow loading information.

Comment: @represton You also need it for wind loading and uplift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend your brace further toward the middle and use corner joist hangers at the wall.

[image]

Comment: I'd agree - make the diagonal bracing longer by extending it down the vertical attachment leg and out along the awning support beam. I'd suggest using a rafter hanger [similar to this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/USP-2-in-x-4-in-18-Gauge-G90-Galvanized-Face-Mount-Joist-Hanger/3374492), but with the bottom angled to accept a sloping rafter instead of a level joist. (They make decorative ones for exposed use like this, they just cost more.) Use the appropriate joist hanger nails or screws - it's well worth it!